# MOBILE enable websites

Tags: php, mobile

I have couple of websites on php. I want to mobile enable them so they can be seen from a smart phone or iphone. Is there any quick conversion tools for these.

I tried the steps in this site and got a 500 exception from hostgator.
http://www.mikeindustries.com/blog/archive/2005/07/make-your-site-mobile-friendly

I am looking for some rad techniques. my sites are not complex. 
for eg. yndc.tradepeacefully.com

Comment: Mobile versions are generally just stripped down copies of the regular site. Remove as much "fluff" as you can, make sure any images you have to serve are "small" (resolution AND size) and that you don't make any assumptions about the width/height of the display device.

Comment: When you get a 500 error, you should check the webserver error logs... They could shed some light on what exactly is going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From hostgator support :
http://support.hostgator.com/articles/hosting-guide/hardware-software/is-php-running-as-apache-or-cgi

Now check the notes on the link you posted, especially note 3 :

> In order to use auto prepending and
>   auto appending, you must be running
>   PHP as a standard Apache module and
>   not “as cgi”. If need be, you can run
>   PHP as Apache sometimes and CGI other
>   times by using your .htaccess file to
>   specify rules.

So this approach won't work on Hostgator (unless you're on dedicated hosting, see the support page), since they're running PHP as CGI...

Answer (score 1):

To mobile-enable your site, you just need two things:

1. Detect the browser's user agent.
2. Forward to a mobile version of the site.

You should be able to find a htaccess file on Google that will accomplish the #1. The hard part is going to be coming up with a new layout for your site that is mobile-friendly.

That part will be mostly written from scratch.

Answer (score 1):

You get the 500 error probably because your hosting provider does not support the php_value in .htaccess files.